# use R to replace "commas" with "dots" for multiple .asc

Tags: r, ascii, gsub

I have about 1000 ascii files where I need to remove the header and than replace commas with dots.

I've already found this answer very helpful for looping the process and removing the header: ([use R to remove header (6 lines) from .asc file (ESRI ascii grid) and export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941312/use-r-to-remove-header-6-lines-from-asc-file-esri-ascii-grid-and-export))

```
setwd("c:/temp/hdr/ascii")
newdir <- "c:/temp/hdr/ascii_no_hdr/"

files <- dir(pattern="*.asc")

for (my.file in files){
  i <- read.table(my.file,skip=16,sep="")
  write.table(i,file=paste(newdir,my.file,sep=""),sep="",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
}
```

How do I integrate a gsub function into the code ?
Sorry I'm fairly new to R.

```
   V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12   V13   V14   V15   V16   V17   V18   V19   V20   V21   V22
1   33,45 33,45 33,64 32,82 32,95 33,52 33,47 33,96 34,28 34,04 34,42 34,26 34,00 33,64 33,60 33,37 33,32 32,59 32,15 31,52 31,20 30,83
2   32,15 32,61 33,24 32,99 32,88 33,22 33,68 34,09 34,59 34,81 34,51 35,25 34,77 34,55 34,13 33,66 33,51 32,92 32,84 32,17 31,87 31,15
3   32,25 32,10 33,05 32,88 32,69 33,03 33,28 34,02 34,40 34,96 35,43 35,55 35,57 35,36 35,06 34,64 34,43 34,43 34,15 33,39 33,13 32,69
4   31,92 31,73 32,31 32,94 32,23 32,44 32,95 33,54 34,17 34,74 35,26 35,58 35,66 36,00 35,81 35,43 35,15 35,04 34,59 34,34 34,17 34,34
5   32,00 31,85 31,52 32,86 32,40 32,27 32,99 33,52 33,89 34,77 35,34 35,58 36,13 36,15 36,07 36,00 35,57 35,64 35,19 34,85 34,77 34,72
6   32,06 32,08 31,77 32,61 32,32 32,27 32,55 33,39 34,06 34,93 35,68 36,04 36,39 36,50 36,37 36,37 36,19 35,72 35,58 35,51 35,04 35,08
7   32,17 32,27 31,50 32,55 32,57 31,79 32,80 33,16 34,09 34,79 35,64 35,87 36,26 36,52
```

[part of one of the files with header already removed]

Comment: Have you tried `dec=","` in the `read.table`

Comment: thank you very much! Thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify `dec=","` in the `read.table` to correctly change the `,` to `.` in the file, i.e. in your code and then `write` the changed file as showed in the OP's code.

```
 setwd("c:/temp/hdr/ascii")
 newdir <- "c:/temp/hdr/ascii_no_hdr/"

 files <- dir(pattern="*.asc")

for (my.file in files){
  i <- read.table(my.file,skip=16,sep="", dec=",") ###here
  write.table(i,file=paste(newdir,my.file,sep=""),
    sep="",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
 }
```